# Wordpress css classes interfere with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom slider for my wordpress page. i've started creating it through a JSFiddle and then i've inserted it into my theme however it seems like there is some other classes or css code, which intefere with the slider, so it wont get the same look. Is this possible to see by inspecting elements? or how can i approach this, since i cant seem to find the issue?

JSFiddle of the slider which is correct

http://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/530/

Here is the link to the wordpress page i've added it to

http://ggwp.dk/test

As you can see it is first of all not centered and then there is the bottom line.

html:

```
<div class="demo">
    <ul id="demo" class="content-slider">

        <li>
            <div class="slider-content">
                <h3 class="center lead league-name">Liga BBVA</h3>
                <div class="row center">
                    <div class="xs-4">
                        <img src="http://demo.themeum.com/sportsline/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/151.png" alt="Barcelona">
                        <strong>Copenhagen Wolves</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="xs-center">
                        <p class="score">3 - 1</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="xs-4">
                        <img src="http://demo.themeum.com/sportsline/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/131.png" alt="Granada">
                        <strong>Yoe Flash Wolves</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slider-content"><h3>2</h3></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slider-content"><h3>3</h3></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slider-content"><h3>4</h3></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slider-content"><h3>5</h3></div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-slider ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.content-slider li {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
.content-slider {
}
.content-slider .slider-content {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 60px 20px;
      display: inline;
}
.demo {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 357px;
    background:url('http://tnuqq21kt870t8n1egkbrmbr.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/MLG-Championship-Anaheim-2014-Crowd-Enrique-Espinoza.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg{
    background:#FFF;
}


.league-name {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.xs-4 {
  width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

.xs-center {
  width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.xs-4 img {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.xs-4 strong {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.xs-center .score {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.lSSlideOuter .lSPager.lSpg {
  background: #FFF;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, there are template CSS that overrides your styles. You have to add the following properties:

```
.post-content .content-slider {
    margin:0;
}

.post-content .slider-content h3 {
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Okay seem to almost fix it. if u take a look at it now and the fiddle the left team text still seem to a bit off the jsfiddle? Do you know why that is ?

Comment: I see, this is not about the layout, but the font-family of the text (in the fiddle you didn't specify any).

Comment: Anyway in your case it wouldn't harm to remove the negative margins from the .row selector: http://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/531/

Comment: If i do that it will show a line at the bottom. Try and look on the test link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**line number 3554** contain below css style.. you reset the this css,

```
.post-content ul {
margin-left : 21px 
}
```

to add css,

```
.post-content ul#demo  {
    margin-left : 0px 
    }
```

or to change

```
.post-content ul {
    margin-left : 0px 
    }
```